# unable to run tensorflow on multiple GPUs

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow

I am running the cifar10 multi-GPU example from the tensorflow repository. I am able to utilize more than one GPUs. My ubuntu PC has two Titan X's, I see memory are fully occupied by the process on both GPUs. However, only one GPU is actually computing. I obtain no speedup. I have tried tensorflow 0.5.0 and 0.6.0 pip binaries. I have also tried compiled from source.

EDIT:
The problem disappeared after I installed an older version of nvidia driver.

Comment: The cifar10 multi-GPU example used to run my machine. After I install newer nvidia driver and newer version of tensorflow, it fails to utilize more than one GPUs.

Comment: How do you know it's not using the second GPU? Also, you can try making session with log_device_placement=True.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I solved the problem by installing an older version of nvidia driver. BTW check GPU utilization using nvidia-smi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem disappeared after I installed an older version (352.55) of nvidia driver.